# Mysqldump exporting extra records than in --where condition

Tags: mysql, database, export, archive

I'm using mysqldump to export old records. However, the dump file has slightly extra rows than the specified --where condition. My table has 2905338 rows. The exported rows should be 635314, but mysqldump is exporting 134 rows extra.

`mysqldump table --no-create-db --no-create-info --skip-add-drop-table --skip-add-locks --skip-disable-keys --skip-set-charset --skip-triggers --where "created BETWEEN '2013-01-01 00:00:00' and '2016-12-01 00:00:00'"`

It is exporting rows of 1 hr extra than the condition. The same is happening with other huge tables.

Comment: Have you tried `SELECT * INTO OUTFILE` and if yes, what was the outcome?

Comment: Try doing `--where "created >= '2013-01-01' and created < '2016-12-01'"` instead. Note that I've added an apostrophe to the end of the string - it was lacking in yours

Comment: What is the datatype of the created column? DATETIME or DATE?

Comment: @andychukse The datatype is TIMESTAMP

Answer (score 0):

Try using

```
 mysqldump table --no-create-db --no-create-info --skip-add-drop-table --skip- 
 add-locks --skip-disable-keys --skip-set-charset --skip-triggers --where  
 "created >= '2013-01-01 00:00:00' and created <= '2016-12-01 00:00:00'"
```

Comment: TIME() function extracts only the time of the timestamp. This wont solve my problem.

Comment: Try the above, I made some changes